# Is a finite dimensional subspace of $L^\infty$ separable?

Tags: general-topology, banach-spaces

I think any finite dimensional normed space is separable so the answer to the above would be yes. But I am not 100% sure since since this is $L^\infty$ which is not separable. Fundamentally I am not grasping the reason why $L^\infty$ is not separable.

Comment: Yes. It is finite dimensional.

Comment: Is $\mathbb{R}$ separable? Is $\mathbb{R}^n$ separable?

Comment: $L^\infty$ is not separable because it has an uncountable subset $D$ such that $\|d-d'\|_\infty =1 $ for all $d \neq d'$ in $D$. You cannot approximate them all using a mere countable set..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any finite-dimensional subspace of a TVS $X$ over $\Bbb R$ is homeomorphic to some $\Bbb R^n$ and thus (locally compact and) separable. This is a standard fact proved in most text books (e.g. Rudin's functional analysis or Dunford and Schwarz).